# how to remove duplicates from string elements within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

```
['tthhee', 'zzeenn', 'ooff', 'ppyytthhoonn', 'bbyy', 'ttiimm', 'ppeetteerrss', 'bbeeaauuttiiffuull', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'uuggllyy..', 'eexxpplliicciitt', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'iimmpplliicciitt..', 'ssiimmppllee', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'ccoommpplleexx..', 'ccoommpplleexx', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'ccoommpplliiccaatteedd..', 'ffllaatt', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'nneesstteedd..', 'ssppaarrssee', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'ddeennssee..', 'rreeaaddaabbiilliittyy', 'ccoouunnttss..', 'ssppeecciiaall', 'ccaasseess', "aarreenn''tt", 'ssppeecciiaall', 'eennoouugghh', 'ttoo', 'bbrreeaakk', 'tthhee', 'rruulleess..', 'aalltthhoouugghh', 'pprraaccttiiccaalliittyy', 'bbeeaattss', 'ppuurriittyy..', 'eerrrroorrss', 'sshhoouulldd', 'nneevveerr', 'ppaassss', 'ssiilleennttllyy..', 'uunnlleessss', 'eexxpplliicciittllyy', 'ssiilleenncceedd..', 'iinn', 'tthhee', 'ffaaccee', 'ooff', 'aammbbiigguuiittyy,,', 'rreeffuussee', 'tthhee', 'tteemmppttaattiioonn', 'ttoo', 'gguueessss..', 'tthheerree', 'sshhoouulldd', 'bbee', 'oonnee----', 'aanndd', 'pprreeffeerraabbllyy', 'oonnllyy', 'oonnee', '----oobbvviioouuss', 'wwaayy', 'ttoo', 'ddoo', 'iitt..', 'aalltthhoouugghh', 'tthhaatt', 'wwaayy', 'mmaayy', 'nnoott', 'bbee', 'oobbvviioouuss', 'aatt', 'ffiirrsstt', 'uunnlleessss', "yyoouu''rree", 'dduuttcchh..', 'nnooww', 'iiss', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', 'nneevveerr..', 'aalltthhoouugghh', 'nneevveerr', 'iiss', 'oofftteenn', 'bbeetttteerr', 'tthhaann', '*rriigghhtt*', 'nnooww..', 'iiff', 'tthhee', 'iimmpplleemmeennttaattiioonn', 'iiss', 'hhaarrdd', 'ttoo', 'eexxppllaaiinn,,', "iitt''ss", 'aa', 'bbaadd', 'iiddeeaa..', 'iiff', 'tthhee', 'iimmpplleemmeennttaattiioonn', 'iiss', 'eeaassyy', 'ttoo', 'eexxppllaaiinn,,', 'iitt', 'mmaayy', 'bbee', 'aa', 'ggoooodd', 'iiddeeaa..', 'nnaammeessppaacceess', 'aarree', 'oonnee', 'hhoonnkkiinngg', 'ggrreeaatt', 'iiddeeaa', '----', "lleett''ss", 'ddoo', 'mmoorree', 'ooff', 'tthhoossee!!']
```

How can we remove the duplicate letters from each string in the list ?

Comment: Do you know how to remove duplicate letters from a single string?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to get as result. Should `ppeetteerrss` result in `peters` or in `petrs` or in `rtspe`?

Comment: It's also not clear if you have trouble doing the same thing for each item in a list.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the name of your list is `words`. Which defined like below for example:

```py
words = ['tthhee', 'zzeenn', 'ooff', 'ppyytthhoonn', 'bbyy', 'ttiimm']
```

If order important for you, you can use following, It keeps the first of the repeating letters and deletes the next ones.:

```py
new_list = [''.join(dict.fromkeys(word)) for word in words]
```

`['the', 'zen', 'of', 'python', 'by', 'tim']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict.from_keys` to ensure keeping unique letters while maintaining the order, and `str.join` to generate again a string:

```
[''.join(dict.fromkeys(x)) for x in input_list]
```

output:

```
['the', 'zen', 'of', 'python', 'by', 'tim', 'petrs',
 'beautifl', 'is', 'betr', 'than', 'ugly.',
 'explict', 'is', 'betr', 'than', 'implct.',
...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you want to keep one letter and remove the following one, you can only take the "even index" of the word:

```
words = ['tthhee', 'zzeenn', 'ooff', 'ppyytthhoonn', 'bbyy']

corrected = [word[::2] for word in words]
print(corrected)

>> ['the', 'zen', 'of', 'python', 'by']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution:

```
your_list= ["".join(set(x)) for x in your_list]
```

output:

```
['eht',
'nez',
'of',
'toynhp',
'by',
'mti',
'rstep',
'atibeluf']
```